# How to print from servlet to webpage?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

Hi I am trying to print the list from servlet to web screen (jsp)
I am using log and it's not working.
Is there anyway to do or am I using this wrong?

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TodoServiceServlet.class.getName());
.....
Todo tmp = pm.getObjectById(Todo.class, user.getEmail());
    System.out.println("user email: " + user.getEmail());

    if(tmp==null){

        log.info("You have not stored any todo lists yet");

    }else{
        System.out.println("user email is there?: " + tmp.getEmail());

        System.out.println("start printing");
        ArrayList<String> todolists = tmp.getList();
        if(todolists==null)
            System.out.println("Arraylist null");

        if(!todolists.isEmpty()){
            for(String t : todolists){
                System.out.println("In the list: " + t);
                log.info("You need to do: " + t);
            }
        }else{
            log.info("You have nothing to do chil out!");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out` would print to "standard out" on the web server (usually the console) not to the screen. What you have to do is instead write to the `HttpServletResponse`

so something like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    try {
        resp.getWriter().println("user email is there?: " + tmp.getEmail());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle your error here

    }
}
```